# Android Background appearing on action bar icons and all views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was working with custom theme abnd I certianly got this weird issue. Background was supposed to appear only for LinearLayout but it suddenly started appearing in ActionBar icons as well as all the Views of the layout.

Here is screen shot:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my custom theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Menu/item attributes -->
<style name="actionMenuViewStyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.ExpandedMenu.Item</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_gradient</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/action_bar_gradient</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>
```

Here is my activity_add.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/HeaderGridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="14"
        app:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textYear"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/year"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/year_spinner"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:prompt="@string/year" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_district"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/district"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/district_spinner"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:prompt="@string/district" /><--Closing of grid and linear layout-->
```

I have not declared background on Manifest file and custom theme but only in activity_add.xml, but I have background in all of ActionBar icons and Views as shown above.
Does anybody knows how to solve this issue? Please help.

Comment: close `<\LinearLayout>` in `activity_add.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such background around action bar appears only if you place android:background in custom_theme. So try removing

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
```

from your custom theme.

Comment: thats silly mistake I made anyway thanks for your good observation.